# Assignment operator of template class

Tags: c++, templates, assignment-operator

I have this example: a class of a matrix and the dimension of the matrix is given as template argument.

```
template <std::size_t DIM>
class Matrix {
   // ...
};

int main()
{
  Matrix<2> m2;
  Matrix<4> m4;

  m2 = m4;
}
```

Wat does my assignment operator have to look like to change the the `DIM` of `m2` from 2 to 4?

Comment: `Matrix<2> m2 ();` will not instantiate a matrix object. it will declare a function.

Comment: my example is a very very easy version of my actual class but in the actual class a construction looks like this: 

Table<int, 3> U ({5,1,10});

that works!, it tested it :) now I think that Matrix<2> m2 (); should also work

Comment: @MariusKüpper: Speculation and fantasizing are never a good way to learn C++ :-(

Comment: What is the "dimension" of a matrix?! A matrix represents a linear map between two vector spaces; it has more than one parameter.

Comment: I have to add that of course in my code the main is properly maid with int main(){... } in my code above I wrote "main:" to make a short example

Comment: In general the assignment operator signature should look like `Matrix<DIM>& operator=(const Matrix<DIM>&);`

Comment: @KerreKSB I have a class where a matrix can have 1 dimension (a simple array) but also 2 dimension (a matrix) but also n dimensions without any problem.
this is a project i'm coding for school and it's demanded by the teacher to implement it like this

Comment: You have to define what it means to perform the assignment before you write the actual code, otherwise, you will get stuck.

Comment: Ah, OK, you're using the words "matrix" and "dimensions" in ways that are very different from their common meanings in mathematics and computing. That's fine, though it may make it a bit harder to connect with people.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes but here i have a problem because it should look like: Matrix<DIM2>& operator=(const Matrix<DIM2>&);  because the two matrix are of a diffrent DIM

Comment: @MariusKüpper The inline template as proposed in Ridchard's answer should do the trick.

Comment: @remyabel as said this is a very easy example of my code, my code is written and also the assignment operator but i don't know how to change the template arg of an object

Comment: You can't change the template argument, it's a static property of the type, not something dynamic that can change at runtime. You can change an `int` from the value 4 to the value 3, but you can't change  it to a `long`. Similarly, you can change a `Matrix<2>`'s value but you can't change its type to `Matrix<4>`

Comment: @MariusKüpper If you *think* that it will work, try it. It won't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Wat does my assignment operator have to look like to change the the DIM of m2 from 2 to 4?

You can't do that, it's impossible.

You can't change the template argument of an object's class type, it's a static property of the type, not something dynamic that can change at runtime.

You can change an `int` from the value 4 to the value 3, but you can't change it to a `long`. Similarly, you can change a `Matrix<2>`'s value but you can't change its type to `Matrix<4>`.

There is no way to do `m2 = m4` and have it mean anything sensible.

Maybe you want the dimension to be a dynamic property of the type, not a template argument:

```
class Matrix {
  std::size_t m_dim;
  // ...
};
```

Now you can change the value at runtime, so assigning to the type can change its `m_dim` value.

Answer (score 7):

```
template <std::size_t DIM>
class Matrix {

  template <std::size_t OtherDim>
  Matrix& operator=(const Matrix<OtherDim>& rhs)
  {
    // whatever magic you need in here
    return *this;
  }

};
```

`Matrix<DIM>` and `Matrix<OtherDim>` are two distinct types.

The first question to ask is, "Is there a logical operation of assigning a `Matrix<4>` to a `Matrix<2>`?".

The answer is probably "no".

But there probably is a valid assignment between `Matrix<2>` and `Matrix<2>`:

```
template <std::size_t DIM>
class Matrix {
  // implement a copy constructor...
  Matrix(const Matrix& rhs)
  : /* copy-initialise all data */
  {
    /* any other copy-related logic */
  }

  // ...and a copy-assignment operator
  Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& rhs)
  {
    if (&rhs != this) {
      Matrix tmp(rhs);
      std::swap(*this, tmp);
    }
    return *this;
  }

};
```

Comment: yes that is what i tried but it don't know how to change the DIM to OtherDim in the operator

Comment: You can't change the Dim, that's part of its type and you can't change an object's type

Comment: @JonathanWakely that is my thought to so this says us that the operator must return an object of Matrix<OtherDim> and it will not return *this but here is my question: if i use an operator like this will the returned object have the name m2 ??

Comment: The first question to ask is, "Is there a logical operation of assigning a Matrix<4> to a Matrix<2>?" the answer is: my prof demands it so I have to implement it :p

Comment: but you want the result of the assignment to be a `Matrix<4>` or a `Matrix<2>`?

Comment: a Matrix<4> but it must have the name "m2" (I'm sorry for my bad explications. I should have given more information in my question :p )

Comment: I removed the comment about the move constructor, since explicitly declaring a copy constructor inhibits the implicit declaration of a move constructor. Furthermore, your implementation of assignment requires that `swap` be specialized somewhere; as it is, the definition is recursive (since `swap` will use assignment).